# TensorFlow: shape rank 2 in tf.matrix_inverse()

Tags: tensorflow, matrix-inverse

I have a problem when I try the tf.matrix_inverse() method.

I have a Tensor of dimension [17,400,400]. And we can read in the API documentation:

> The input is a tensor of shape [..., M, M] whose inner-most 2 dimensions form square matrices.

In my case M=400. And when I try to calculate the 17 inverse matrix:

```
Out[56]: L
Out[57]: <tf.Tensor 'while_4/Exit_1:0' shape=(17, 400, 400) dtype=float32>
Out[59]: InvL = tf.matrix_inverse(L)
        ValueError: Shape (17, 400, 400) must have rank 2
```

I understand that L have a shape rank 2, but the method fails. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. Any help?

Comment: Are you using the latest code? With the latest code, this works. `x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.rand(17, 400, 400)); z = tf.matrix_inverse(x)`. If you change the dimensions, you'll get an error saying `Dimensions must be equal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation you are referencing is only for tensorflow release r0.11 or the master version.

Check your tensorflow version first:

```
import tensorflow
tensorflow.__version__
```

For release prior to r0.11, as the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#matrix_inverse) says here:

[image: tf.matrix_inverse doc for r0.10]

It doesn't support inverting tensors with rank!=2

Try [update the tensorflow to r0.11](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#download-and-setup) or pull directly from their github master branch

Comment: Thanks, I have r0.10